# Apache: Website don't load when SSL is installed

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I have a tomcat web app in an `Ubuntu` server. The web app is deployed as `ROOT`. I have installed `apache2` and via a `VirtualHost` I pointed the IP directly to the tomcat web app. So I can access the site via the IP (and domain) directly like `125.20.20.50` or `example.com`.

Please check the below file, which is the `000-default.conf` in `\etc\apache2\sites-enabled\`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/

    ServerName portal.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.79/webapps/ROOT/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine On
        # Set the path to SSL certificate
        # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xyz_key.key
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xyz_certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/STAR_example_com.ca-bundle
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
        ServerName portal.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The certificate is fine, but when I run the `portal.example.com` I get a `503 Service Unavailable` error. I checked this in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file and the error is as below.

```
[Fri Aug 04 07:33:22.185014 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 2056] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:8080 (0.0.0.0) failed
    [Fri Aug 04 07:33:22.185055 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 2056] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
    [Fri Aug 04 07:33:22.185059 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2056] [client 113.59.205.35:49453] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0, referer: http://portal.example.com/
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address to connect to. Enter the correct IP address, most probably `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Thanks for the reply. My port 80 forward is working fine with that configuration. In which place I ahve to change please?

Comment: ```ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse``` here

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Anyuway, now I can access the site with both HTTP and HTTPS. I want the URL to convert to HTTPS. How can I do that?